# Vue app.js colliding with other JavaScript files on homepage (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I included Vuejs in my existing project but now it is affecting my original theme JavaScript files.
Without app.js on my homepage, everything works fine. But when I include it, All UI effects and functionalities on my original theme js file including sliders, canvas, carousels, and dropdowns all stops working.

How do I stop Vue from colliding with my theme js and causing it to break

Comment: Are you using scoped styles for your Vue components? Or do the Vue components use class names and or global styles that could effect other class names and/or global styles?

Comment: No I did not add any other class names and styles. This is an original working theme. It just breaks when I include <script src="app.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

### regarding CSS collisions...

You can solve by making sure all your css is getting scoped.

instead of

```html
<style>
/* global styles */
</style>
```

use

```html
<style scoped>
/* local styles */
</style>
```

Vue will then compile your css to have generated is like `h1[data-v-f3f3eg9]` that will prevent other elements on the page from being formatted by your vue code. It will not, however, prevent your page code from affecting the vue components unless you add css resets to you components.

#### regarding JS code...

it's hard to tell without seeing what the collisions are. AFAIK There's no magical setting for that.

Comment: I don't know if this would help but the JS file is actually another compiled bundle just like Vue app.js

Comment: I don't know which framework it was written on probably react or something else

Comment: should be able to determine from the dependencies that are included, is it loading react from a CDN?

Comment: Yes now that you mentioned it. It is

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for this collision

Put your `app.js` at the top of your script links like:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Then

```
<script> $.noConflict(); /script>
```

After that put your other JavaScript it will work fine.

Comment: Mention `why` as well. Explain the answer that you're suggesting.